# How to convert CharSequence to String?

Tags: java, string, charsequence

How can I convert a Java `CharSequence` to a `String`?

Comment: Safest way: `String.valueOf(charSequence)`. [Here is the detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707556/how-to-convert-charsequence-to-string/69848794#69848794)

Answer (score 392, accepted):

By invoking its [`toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#toString%28%29) method.

> Returns a string containing the characters in this sequence in the same order as this sequence. The length of the string will be the length of this sequence.

Comment: @TheOnlyAnil, does calling [`setText(CharSequence)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) not do what you need?

Comment: I want to make actionBar title clickable.

Comment: @TheOnlyAnil, maybe you should ask that as a question.  Comments on an answer to a tangentially related question are not a good place to try and tease out your requirements.

Comment: Stackoverflow won't let me post any question. :/ btw I did that last night. Custom actionbar is the solution :)

Comment: By using the toString() method my CharSequence is displaying as, "[Ljava.lang.CharSequence;@26ae880a", not the text that was actually sent.  toString() doesn't work.

Comment: @WillByers that output looks like the toString of a CharSequence array, not a CharSequence.

Comment: Wanted to upvote, but can't change 333 to 334, sorry!

Comment: @Hibbem someone else did it for you ;-)

Comment: @JamesFranken I'm having the same issue. I guess it's up to the implementer of the interface how this behaves. I solved it by using this instead: `String.join("", myCharSequence)`

Answer (score 91):

**There is a subtle issue here that is a bit of a gotcha.**

The `toString()` method has a base implementation in `Object`. `CharSequence` is an interface; and although the `toString()` method appears as part of that interface, there is nothing at compile-time that will force you to override it and honor the additional constraints that the `CharSequence` `toString()` method's javadoc puts on the `toString()` method; ie that it should return a string containing the characters in the order returned by `charAt()`.

Your IDE won't even help you out by reminding that you that you *probably should* override `toString()`. For example, in intellij, this is what you'll see if you create a new `CharSequence` implementation: http://puu.sh/2w1RJ. Note the absence of `toString()`.

If you rely on `toString()` on an arbitrary `CharSequence`, it *should* work provided the `CharSequence` implementer did their job properly. But if you want to avoid any uncertainty altogether, you should use a `StringBuilder` and `append()`, like so:

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(charSequence.length());
sb.append(charSequence);
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: You shouldn't make mistakes/make your code worse because others might have made a mistake.

Comment: return new StringBuilder(charSequence).toString(); is a single liner equivalent.

Comment: **THIS ANSWER IS WRONG** The `CharSequence` interface explicitly defines `toString()` - the _implementor_ won't have missed this.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#toString%28%29) states "Returns a string containing the characters in this sequence in the same order as this sequence. The length of the string will be the length of this sequence" since inception in [1.4](https://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/java/jdk1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#toString%28%29).  _People, please verify what you upvote_

Comment: Incidentially `StringBuilder` implements `CharSequence`, so you're now _trusting_ the StringBuilder implementer did their job properly ツ

Comment: The difference being, it's relatively simple to inspect StringBuilder.java and satisfy yourself that StringBuilder.toString() is doing the correct thing (it is), while it's another matter to verify it is true for the limitless number of custom CharSequence implementations that do or could exist.

Comment: This is silly. If you don't trust the implementer to follow the contract, all bets are off. Passing it as a parameter to `StringBuilder` could just as well fail to do what you expect. The same goes for any other interface, such as `List` or `Set`, in particular their `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods which will compile without overrides, but *must* be overridden according to the contract.

Comment: Sure, I agree. However this is more about how the interface actually _hijacks_ the toString() method and usurps its original purpose entirely. Consider the documentation on the base method: "In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read." The intent of toString() is to provide a human-readable representation of an object, not a core piece of programmatic functionality.

Comment: The fact that the interface does this is arguably a poor decision in that regard, and my answer simply highlights that this is an _easier than normal_ place for human error to occur.

Comment: @shmosel in fact, an implementer is following interface contract, it implements given method to represent the object as a string, the problem is with its representation that sometimes has nothing to do with CharSequence, but description of the object (try adding CharSequence interface to the ArrayList<Char>, for example, you'll have default implementation of toString(), but it's not the one you want to have with CharSequence, even more, some tools won't even notify you that there is potential bug in your code if you won't implement that method explicitly)

Comment: @Pavlus I think you're missing the fact that `CharSequence` [overrides the contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#toString()) to return exactly what anyone would expect.

Comment: @shmosel do I? What led you to such conclusion?

Comment: @Pavlus It sounds like you're trying to say the default `toString()` doesn't necessarily conform with what you'd expect from a `CharSequence`. If that's not it, I have no idea what you're saying.

Comment: @shmosel yes, it doesn't. Default contract is to represent object as `String`, `CharSequence` specifies how exactly do that (it still represents the object but in the specified way)

Comment: this actually causes the string to be copied twice, once in the sb.append(), and another time in the sb.toString()

Comment: The actual issue is that you can infer *meaning* just by having a string. There should be subtyping, when getting a `String` from a generic `Object` method: something like `HashCodeString` or `ObjectSystemString` or whatever. It's the return type from `toString` that is too generic, and exposes the side to ambiguity. Arguing on using a different object for generating the string, or on using a differently named method (that might *still* retain ambiguity) misses the point, IMHO.

Comment: The expectation from `toString` on an `Object` and onto a `CharSequence` is to get returned a meaningful type. How the method is called is more for readability purposes; the name itself doesn't infer any guarantee about the context. What if I have a `SyntheticMaterial` with a `toString` method? What would *string* mean here? It might mean different things depending on the context (https://thexplorion.com/different-types-of-strings/). Focusing on the name is misleading; we should focus on the return types, to discern the use case.

Comment: @earcam Your comment is wrong. Yes, `toString()` is defined in the interface, but that puts no obligation on the implementing classes to override it. It just says that is has to be implemented in the concrete class. Which it will be, because it's defined on Object, and everything is an object. See the example:  https://ideone.com/fkvReI

Comment: @Knox, so the CharSequence explicitly declares toString and the associated JavaDoc states the expected behaviour - but your saying implementations may choose to ignore this as it won't be a compilation issue...     Erm, those implementations are in violation of the expected behaviour, whether the compiler cares or not.

Comment: @earcam My problem was with saying "The CharSequence interface explicitly defines toString() - the _implementor_ **won't** have missed this." At least to me, that reads as if putting the method definition in the interface is what guarantees implementations will be forced to address it (override it), when in reality that's not the case. I interpret it that way because you said "won't", which to me means an impossibility (compiler error). I'm pointing it out because I've seen people make the assumption that putting toString() in an interface actually does require the implementations override it.

Comment: @earcam I agree with your conclusion that it's almost certainly unnecessary to be suspicious that the Javadocs weren't honored, especially in a java.lang class. I'm just trying to be careful about saying on a more general level that redefining methods from Object on an interface actually doesn't do anything besides create an opportunity to add comments through Javadocs

Comment: Also, not only is it *possible* for the implementer to have missed it (meaning "won't" is probably not an accurate way to describe this), but I think it's *trivial* to have missed it given what @Pavlus mentioned above. No errors, no warnings, and it works incorrectly (according to the Javadoc) by default since `toString()` is always implemented.

Comment: @Knox, (1/2) thank you for polite and intellect based argument (sincerely) - it sent me on a long tangent til sleep/forced-browser reset...   
Sharing rabbit-hole; 6y after my "someone on teh internet is wrong" comment, and considering your **valid counter arguments**.

IMO the **solution** is new compiler warnings;  very unlikely future versions of Java will/can ever allow an iface to abstract a method mandated to extend Object.  So the only `java.lang` v8+ "fix" would be to redefine as default method that throws..   yuk + breaking change

Comment: @Knox, (2/2)  solution via javac WDYT? I rabbit-holed searching for other soft-fails that a compiler could/should pick up - some at least current JDK err/warn codebase can certainly handle...  When javac warnings raised as errors, this would meet both our concerns (implementations not assumed to follow weak JavaDoc contracts and consumers not needing to tediously guard)
It is 1) an implementor's easy mistake, 2) exasperated by a language design fail - strongly typed, compiled language can resolve lang-fail.

Answer (score 31):

You can directly use String.valueOf()

```
String.valueOf(charSequence)
```

Though this is same as `toString()` it does a null check on the `charSequence` before actually calling toString.

This is useful when a method can return either a `charSequence` or `null` value.

Comment: This actually just bit me today.
if `charSequence` is null then the returned string will be `"null"` and not `null`.

Comment: Oh. Makes sense. I will remove this answer

Comment: I think this is perfect for some cases.

Comment: This is quite same as charSequence.toString()       looking at the definition in libcore/ojluni/src/main/java/java/lang/String.java                                             public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
        return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
    }

Answer (score 17):

## The Safest Way

```
String string = String.valueOf(charSequence);
```

---

### Let's Dive Deep

There are 3 common ways that we can try to convert a `CharSequence` to `String`:

1. **Type Casting**: `String string = (String) charSequence;`
2. **Calling `toString()`**: `String string = charSequence.toString();`
3. **`String.valueOf()` Method**: `String string = String.valueOf(charSequence);`

And if we run these where `CharSequence charSequence = "a simple string";` then all 3 of them will produce the expected result.

The problem happens when we are not sure about the nature of the `CharSequence`. In fact, `CharSequence` is an `interface` that several other classes implement, like- `String`, `CharBuffer`, `StringBuffer`, etc. So, converting a `String` to a `CharSequence` is a straightforward assignment operation, no casting or anything is required. But, for the opposite, [Upcasting](https://www.javatpoint.com/upcasting-and-downcasting-in-java), it is not true.

If we are sure that the `CharSequence` is actually an object of `String`, only then we can use option 1- Type Casting. Otherwise, we will get a `ClassCastException`. Option 2 and 3 are safe in this case.

On the other side, if the `CharSequence` is `null` then option 2, calling `toString()`, will give a `NullPointerException`.

Now internally, `String.valueOf()` method calls the `toString()` method after doing a `null` check. So, it is the safest way. [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-):

> if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of obj.toString() is returned.

---

Please be aware: If `CharSequence` is `null` then `String.valueOf()` method return the string- `"null"`, **not `null` value**.

Comment: `new StringBuilder(charSequence).toString();` will through **NullPointerException** if `charSequence` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert an array of CharSequence,
You can simply do this and can also be store it in a String[] variable.

```
CharSequence[] textMsgs = (CharSequence[])sbm.getNotification().extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT_LINES);
if (textMsgs != null) {
   for (CharSequence msg : textMsgs) {
       Log.e("Msg", msg.toString());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution.

As stated before `charSequence.toString()` is not null safe and

`String.valueOf(charSequence)` will produce a `"null"` if `charSequence` is `null`.

If this is not what you wanted you could use:

`Objects.toString(charSequence, null)`. The second argument is the nullDefault.

This will do essentially:

```java
  if(charSequence == null) {
    return null;
  }
  return String.valueOf(charSequence);
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-

Comment: This is way better for null handling :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can une Stringbuilder.

```
new StringBuilder(charSequence).toString();
```