# Any clue to explain why CursorFilter is throwing a NPE when using this custom FilterQueryProvider?

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, autocompletetextview, android-cursoradapter

After initializing a `CursorAdapter` I tried to set the following `FilterQueryProvider` in order to supply results to an `AutoCompleteTextView`.

```
adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
    @Override
    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
        return databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM code WHERE title MATCH ?", new String[]{constraint.toString()});
    }
});
```

The problem is that when I try to call `toString` on the parameter `constraint`, a `NPE` is logged ( assumably by `Log.d` because the log is `blue` in logcat).

> An exception occured during performFiltering()!
>
> Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String
>   java.lang.CharSequence.toString()' on a null object reference

I have checked, constraint is definitely not null.

**Full stacktrace (in blue, so caught and logged)**:

```
12-12 08:55:39.212   9911-10080/com.example W/Filter﹕ An exception occured during performFiltering()!
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.lang.CharSequence.toString()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.fragments.FooFragment$1.runQuery(FooFragment.java:102)
            at android.widget.CursorAdapter.runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CursorAdapter.java:395)
            at android.widget.CursorFilter.performFiltering(CursorFilter.java:49)
            at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: do you have a more complete stacktrace?

Comment: (i still think `constraint` is null, though)

Comment: @njzk2 If I log `constraint`, I get exactly what I had typed in.  It definitely isn't null in `runQuery`.  
`12-12 09:28:37.131  13333-13858/com.example D/CONSTRAINT﹕ ch`

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707556/how-to-convert-charsequence-to-string-in-java

Comment: is that the `runQuery` that is at `FooFragment.java:102`? Did you check that `constraint` is not null right before the crash? Did you try to log it every time you step into `runQuery`? There may be cases where it is null (typically when you clear the edit text)